# Clarifying a definition of cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, permutation-cycles

> Let $E$ be a finite set, $\xi\in\mathfrak{S}_{E}$, and
>   $\overline{\xi}$ the subgroup of $\mathfrak{S}_{E}$ generated by
>   $\xi$. $\xi$ is called a cycle if, under the operation of
>   $\overline{\xi}$ on $E$, there exists one and only one orbit which is
>   not reduced to a single element. This orbit is called the support of
>   $\xi$.
>
> The support $supp(\xi)$ of $\xi$ is the set of $x\in E$ such that
>   $\xi(x)\neq x$

I am not sure that I understand this definition well. What are the data of a cycle---I mean: what am I really given when I'm given a cycle? Besides the operation of $\overline{\xi}$ on $E$, I suppose I have a subset of $E$, a unique $\overline{\xi}$-orbit, which has at least two elements. And why is this subset/orbit equal to $supp(\xi)$?

Any clarifications of this definition will be appreciated.

Comment: Each permutation has a unique representation as a product of disjoint cycles. For instance, let us work in the group of permutations of the set $E=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Then the cycle $(1,4,2,6,9)$ is the permutation mapping $1\to4\to2\to6\to 9\to 1$, and letting all other symbols fixed. This is a cycle. Its support is the set with elements $1,4,2,6,9$. The product of cycles $(1,4,2,6,9)(57)$ is not a cycle. Which is the orbit of $1$? Which is the orbit of $5$?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296695/can-i-get-disjoint-cycles-decomposition-of-sigma-in-s-n-from-the-partition-o/3297080#3297080

Answer (score 1):

Your definition says that a permutation $\xi \in \mathfrak{S}_{E}$ is a *cycle* if the natural action of $\bar \xi \le \mathfrak{S}_{E}$ on the set $E$ (*i.e.* the action of $\bar \xi$ as a group of permutations on $E$) has just one orbit of cardinality $>1$. Therefore, for a convenient labelling of the elements of $E$, say $E=\{x_1,\dots,x_{|E|}\}$, the orbits are:

\begin{alignat}{1}
O(x_1)&= \{\xi(x_1)=x_1\} \\
O(x_2)&= \{\xi(x_2)=x_2\} \\
\dots \\
supp(\xi):=O(x_k)&= \{\xi(x_k),\xi^2(x_k),\dots,\xi^{|E|-k+1}(x_k)=x_k\} \\
&= \{\xi(x_k),\xi(\xi(x_k)),\dots,\xi(\xi^{|E|-k}(x_k))\} \\
&= \{x\in E \mid \xi(x)\ne x\} \\
\end{alignat}

for some $k$, $2 \le k \le |E|-1$.